# Use matplotrust with python3 interpreter in pyenv

Tags: python-3.x, rust

### My Environment

- Ubuntu 18.04
- Python 3.7.3 (`~/.pyenv/shims/python`)
- Rust (cargo 1.36.0)

### Problem

I am a beginner of the Rust language and try to make plot with `matplotrust` crate. I wrote the code like following,

```rust
extern crate matplotrust;

use matplotrust::{line_plot, Figure};

fn main() {
    // load values in text file
    let result = std::fs::read_to_string("test.txt");
    let content = match result {
        Ok(content) => content,
        Err(error) => {
            panic!("Could not read file: {}", error);
        }
    };
    let lines_array: Vec<&str> = content.trim().split("\n").collect();

    // insert values in vectors x and y
    let mut x: Vec<f32> = Vec::new();
    let mut y: Vec<f32> = Vec::new();
    for line in lines_array {
        let pair: Vec<&str> = line.trim().split(" ").collect();
        x.push(pair[0].parse().unwrap());
        y.push(pair[1].parse().unwrap());
    }

    // plot y against x
    let lp = line_plot::<f32, f32>(x, y, None);
    let mut figure = Figure::new();
    figure.add_plot(lp.clone());
    figure.add_plot(lp.clone());

    print!("{:?}", figure.save("./test.png", None));
 }
```

I could build this code, but in the runtime, an error occurs.

```sh
thread 'main' panicked at 'python binary not found at /usr/local/bin/python3: Os { code: 2, kind: NotFound, message: "No such file or directory" }', src/libcore/result.rs:999:5
note: Run with `RUST_BACKTRACE=1` environment variable to display a backtrace.
```

It says python path is wrong. But in my case I use pyenv and does not install python3 in this directory.

How to solve this problem?

### What I tried

I tried to install python3 in `/usr/local/bin` with `apt install` but shell says python3 has already been install with pyenv...

Comment: Try `figure.save("./test.png", Some ("/path/to/python"))`

Answer (score 0):

> @Jmb's comment fixed the user's issue. Writing an answer just to show how to proceed in situations like this one.

`matplotlib` Rust crate documentation isn't really good (none). In this case, you have to check [source code](https://docs.rs/matplotrust/0.1.7/src/matplotrust/lib.rs.html#119-136) of the [`Figure.save()`](https://docs.rs/matplotrust/0.1.7/matplotrust/struct.Figure.html#method.save) method:

```rust
pub fn save(&mut self, output: &str, path: Option<&str>) -> (String, String, String) {
    self.script += &format!("plt.savefig('{}')\n", output);
    // create a temporary file
    let mut tmpfile: NamedTempFile = tempfile::NamedTempFile::new().unwrap();
    tmpfile.write_all(self.script.as_bytes());

    let python_path = match path {
        Some(s) => s,
        None => "/usr/local/bin/python3"
    };

    fs::metadata(python_path).expect("python binary not found at /usr/local/bin/python3");
    let mut echo_hello = Command::new(python_path);
    echo_hello.arg(tmpfile.path());
    echo_hello.output().expect("failed to execute process");

    return (self.script.to_string(), output.to_string(), tmpfile.path().to_str().unwrap().to_string());
}
```

The important part is this one:

```rust
let python_path = match path {
    Some(s) => s,
    None => "/usr/local/bin/python3"
};
```

You called `figure.save("./test.png", None)` -> `/usr/local/bin/python3`. As @Jmb pointed out, you can specify the Python 3 interpreter path via `figure.save("./test.png", Some("/path/to/python3"))` to make it working.